# Watershed using c# or c++

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, watershed

I am trying to convert the Matlab function `watershed` into C# or C++.

I tried to use [this code](http://pastebin.com/KXnJ5XkP) but `CvFindContours` returns `NULL` with [this image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/259/normalnx.jpg/).

I also tried to use [this implementation](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/11/Watershed-Image-Segmentation-in-C.aspx) but I had issues with `FilterGrayToGray`.

Does anyone knows how I can solve my problems or how I can calculate watershed on my image? Can someone explain me more precisely meyers flood algorithm for watershed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [watershed](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#void%20watershed%28InputArray%20image,%20InputOutputArray%20markers%29) algorithm provided by OpenCV? Also, [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/watershed.cpp) is an example of how to use `watershed` with OpenCV. Hope that is helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

Although I think the solution given (OpenCV like) is good, you could also search for a different implementation of watershed. Search for Luc Vincent and Pierre Soille "Watersheds in Digital spaces: an efficient algorithm based on immersion simulations".